# Java, Hibernate, How to set Envers, so it won't create new versions if only one one field changed?

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

As in the title. I have an entity with lot of fields, but every time this entity is saved to data base, envers creates another version event if the only thing that changed is "modificationTimestamp". Is there any way to ignore that one field? But it also need to be written into db if any other field changes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to added the `@NotAudited` annotation to that property in your model.  This means that field will no longer be used in the delta comparison to determine if the entity was modified and thus will no longer trigger an audit row to be added.

This also means you'll have a small inconsistency in your audit data because entries added prior will contain a value in this `modificationTimestamp` column where-as rows after adding the annotation will begin to contain *null* values because Envers no longer tracks this column.

If you don't need the values in the older rows, you can safely drop the column manually from the audit schema if its a value that is of no importance from an audit history perspective.

If you need the older values but the audit schema column was created with a *not-null* constraint in someway, you may need to alter the schema manually and allow it to insert null values simply due to the change in the behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but this is only half success, this `modificationTimeStamp` can't be null, this values are needed, but they should not trigger envers. That is the problem.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you cannot use the timestamp stored in the Envers REVINFO entity structure instead?  If you could, then you could eliminate or at the very least use `@NotAudited` to avoid the column triggering unnecessary Envers changes.  Otherwise at least presently, I guess your only option would be to read up on conditional auditing in the documentation.

Comment: @Naros Does `@NotAudited` necessitate that the default _AUD table must have that column?

Comment: @DelPate: If a property is `@NotAudited`, you do not need it in your history table. It does not matter, whether it has the default `_AUD` suffix or any other custom suffix.